# Cannot get text in TextField to display

Tags: flash, actionscript, textfield

I'm trying to create a `TextField` dynamically in ActionScript 3. The code below draws the text box itself (which in this case is just a red rectangle), but the string `"Add text here"` is not displayed. What can I do to fix this problem?

```
var d:Number = mc.getNextHighestDepth();

var x:Number = (screenWidth - boxWidth) / 2;
var y:Number = (screenHeight - boxHeight) / 2;

var w:Number = boxWidth;
var h:Number = boxHeight;

notification = mc.createTextField("Text", d, x, y, w, h);
notification.background = true;
notification.backgroundColor = 0xFF0000;
notification.selectable = false;
notification.wordWrap = true;
notification.text = "Add text here";
```

Comment: Make sure you embed the font you set for the `TextField`. You assign a `TextFormat` object to the `defaultTextFormat` property of the `TextField` and also call the `setTextFormat(format)` method of the `TextField` when changing fonts. Posting your `mc.createTextField` method source would also help, as we can't really see what you do in there. As @Discipol answered, you'll also need to add any kind of `DisplayObject` to the `DisplayList` to make it visible, but if the red rectangle is drawn I assume you already added it.

Comment: What do you mean post the source of `ms.creatyeTextField`? It's the standard [MovieClip.createTextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001286.html) method.

Comment: Oh, sorry I couldn't catch that you're actually using AS2 API and I thought you had a child class of `MovieClip`. So in Actionscript 3 you don't create a `TextField` like that. The correct way to create a `TextField` in AS3 is as follows: `var tf:TextField = new TextField();`
Then you add it as a child to a parent `DisplayObjectContainer` and set a `TextFormat` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do addChild( notification ) so that the textField is added to the display list.